# Too much memory used with ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I wrote a OSX App using ARC, just load a tableview without any cells,the memory is up to 50M+,
I want to know any way to optimize it.
(Can not use **release** , I can not find any other way)

================================= UPDATE========================================

I created a demo Application , just a blank window, the memory is up to 40M+, sigh

Comment: how many images did you load?

Comment: @holex nothing, just load a empty tableview.

Comment: @Veelian Are we talking about physical or virtual memory? Because OS X is pretty generous in giving away virtual memory which isn't backed by physical memory.

Comment: In general, if you aren't actually experience any performance problems or receiving memory warnings (on the device, not on the simulator), then don't worry about it. Complete the feature first and tune later if needed. Also, @ysjoon has the right answer.

Comment: @sosborn Thanks, it is a OSX app of course on Mac,In Activity Monitor I sorted app by memory , my app is the sixth one so I think it is un normal.

Comment: My advice still stands. By the way, take a look at the apps below yours in Activity Monitor? Are they actually apps with a GUI? Also, as @JustSid said, is that physical or virtual memory? Regardless, you are worrying about something that is not really an issue. Write your app, then worry about that stuff (if you see performance problems). By the way, have you used instruments at all? This is a good chance to do that. It will show you what the memory is being allocated for. ARC has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Virtual memory is meaningless for 99% of uses; the best approximation of "how much memory your app is using" is probably "Real Private Memory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't actually be a difference between using ARC or not--think of ARC as adding `release` calls for you automatically. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068312/how-to-free-memory-in-arc-for-high-memory-usage-graphics-render) has an illustration of this point.

Comment: You mean just set property=nil if not used?

Comment: yes, to set the unused `strong` pointers to `nil` says to the `ARC` the current object is not needed anymore.